# Center & Zoom a KML File Created in Google Earth, on a web page

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, coordinates, kml

I created a KML file that defines several zones using polygons, in Google Earth. My plan was to just use this file on my wordpress site, along with "comprehensive google maps plugin" for wordpress. However, it turns out that while it works, per the developer, I am unable to set a center or zoom. I want to zoom to 10, and center at specific coordinates. I have googled and researched and I keep coming up with a few scripts, but its a bit confusing to me what i would even do with them. This is my first foray into KML. Is there something i can add into the KML file that was generated by google earth, that would  allow me to accomplish this? any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing you can add to the KML. There is also nothing you can do when  you use this plugin, there is no option to center the map when using this plugin.

Comment: the plugin author states in the FAQ that I would need to set the zoom in the KML file, thats why i was thinking it would be possible. If its not, is there any way i can accomplish this on my wordpress site, even without this plugin? im not attached to the plugin. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [WP Flexible Map](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-flexible-map/) instead. It allows you to specify zoom on a KML map, and also gives you access to the map object so that you can set centre after it loads.

Example of shortcode to load KML file; NB: per [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-flexible-map/faq/), I set an id from which a JavaScript global variable name is later derived. [Edit: I'm an idiot, I copypasta'd the wrong example! fixed]

```
[flexiblemap id="exmap" zoom="14" width="500" height="400"
    src="http://snippets.webaware.com.au/maps/example-toronto.kml"]
```

Now, add this code to a plugin (or your theme's functions.php if you wish):

```
add_filter('flexmap_shortcode_html', 'filterFlxmapShortcodeHtml', 10, 2);

/**
* append our script to the end of the map shortcode's HTML
* @param string $html
* @param array $attrs the shortcode's array of attributes/parameters
* @return string
*/
function filterFlxmapShortcodeHtml($html, $attrs) {
    $html .= <<<HTML
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    flxmap_exmap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng("12.345", "32.109"));
});
</script>

HTML;

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: this seems great, but where do i add the link to the actual kml? I installed the plugin, put your code in my themes functions file, and used your shortcode, only i added the src="my kml file". I get the map with the zoom and center perfect, but it seems to be ignoring my KML file.

Comment: actually, this worked great! I just needed to add the src, and remove the "center" parameters from the shortcode. Now i just need to figure out how to get rid of the strange white pixels that show under the google map bubbles...thanks for your help!!!

Comment: The "strange white pixels" bit might be a CSS problem. Use Chrome's Inspect Element to see what they are, and what CSS is affecting them, then try to add a remedy to your theme's CSS.

Comment: Sorry about the shortcode example mixup, that was a copypasta disaster :(

Comment: yup, it was a css problem. i had a background color set for images...took care of that. No prob about the shortcode, this solution was awesome! thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, there is nothing you can do when you use the WP-plugin.

But when you build the map without the plugin, use the options `center` and `zoom` of the map to set zoom and center.

To prevent the map from panning to the contents of the KML-layer, set the option `preserveViewport` of the KML-Layer to true.

Example:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.519,13.406),
  zoom: 12
});
new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://example.com/example.xml',
                         {preserveViewport: true, map:map});
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do, im just not sure how. I created the map in google earth, visually. I cant find a way to choose the center and zoom in google earth. so now i have the KML file, but i cant figure out how this code would go in there.